# method on the link in facelat template JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink

I work with JSF2.0 
when I use this tag in my facelet template

```
<li><a class="identifiant" href="/impression/faces/vues_utilisateur/#{userController.deconnecter}.xhtml"><h:graphicImage library="images" name="facebook.png" /></a></li>
```

all calls to this managedBean "userController" after the tag above  : I don't have a result althrough I don't press this link, but if I call another managedBean : I have a result

but when I change this line by :

```
<li><a class="identifiant" href="/impression/faces/vues_utilisateur/login.xhtml"><h:graphicImage library="images" name="facebook.png" /></a></li>
```

it works
but I want to use the first because I want to execute a method when the user press this link
and I won't use h:commandlink because the css of the list  don't work well
do you have any idea
thanks

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the source of the page in the browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Firefox/Chrome) to see what is the HTML generated for the links, and that will probably help you. Then, you may try to explain a little better what is the result are getting and what is that you actually want.

Comment: I think using <h:commandLink> and fixing your css is the right way to do. Post some code and screenshots on whats going wrong with the css.